# Fixing responsive navbar dropdown issue when resizing back from mobile size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you take a look at

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/

in Desktop (large browser), the dropdown initially works. However, if you reduce the width until the menu options decrease, open and close the dropdown, and then increase the width the dropdown no longer works properly.

[image]

Any fixes for this?

**Update.** Apparently this is Chrome and IE issue. Works ok in FF.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The following css fixed the problem for me:

```
@media screen and (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
.navbar-collapse {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
}
```

And here is where i found the fix: [Navbar Overflow Issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9535)

Hope this helps! =]